# Show that the group of linear transformations that preserve the Minkowski product is isomorphic to the matrix group O(1,n)

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've really been struggling with this problem:

Show that the group of all linear isometries (i.e linear transformations on $\mathbb R^{1,n}$ that preserve the Minkowski product) is isomorphic to the matrix group $O(1,n):=\{A \in GL(n+1,\mathbb R): A^TSA=S\}$ where 
$S=diag(-1,1,...,1) \in GL(n+1,\Bbb R)$.

I'm not sure how to show this explicitly. I can see that there is a relation between the Minkowski product's signs and the S matrix's diagonal elements. I also know that the isometry condition is equivalent to $Ax \oplus Ay = x \oplus y$ $ \forall x,y \in \mathbb R^{1,n} $ where $ \oplus $ is the Minkowski product

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix that represents the Minkowski inner product in the standard basis is precisely $S$. That is to say, for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ we have $x \oplus y = x^t S y$. Therefore $$Ax \oplus Ay = x\oplus y \quad \forall x,y \iff x^t (A^tSA)y = xSy \quad \forall x,y \iff A^t S A = A.$$

Comment: Thanks again :) After your last explanation this one made alot more sense! All the best!

Comment: Just checking this again. I think there's a typo with the final implication. It should be $A^{t}SA = S$